# Yoast SEO plugin "could detect no serious SEO problems" on dashboard

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

In the Yoast SEO plugin dashboard (SEO -> General - Yoast SEO) of my wordpress blog, I see an orange check mark and the assuring text "Problems (0) Good job! We could detect no serious SEO problems" on dashboard. There is also a green check mark at "SEO settings configured". But when I inspect the same blog using external tools, like SISTRIX or Google Search Console, many errors and warnings are displayed, like missing META data etc.

On the wordpress posts page, there are warnings in the Yoast columns "SEO Score" and "Readability Score", some status are yellow, some are red, and many SEO scores are gray when there are no focus keywords defined for the respective post yet.

What do I have to do to make Yoast SEO display those problems on its dashboard instead of the misleading "Problems (0)" which might lead to the wrong conclusion that there is no more optimization necessary.

Comment: You should ask the plugin developer

Comment: I filed an issue here: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/14142